# MSAL confirmation dialog in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-msal

We are using the Microsoft MSAL library to authenticate our users.  When a user needs to login, they are shown this dialog each time.  Is there a way to disable this prompt so the login experience is more seamless?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pop-up occurs anytime the app uses SFAuthenticationSession or ASWebAuthenticationSession, MSAL.NET does not control what is displayed there, as that is the point of the pop up, it is to initialize a private dialog with the user, outside of the app. From Apple's developer site: " users are prompted by a dialog to give explicit consent, allowing the application to access the website’s data in Safari. When the webpage is presented, it runs in a separate process, so the user and web service are guaranteed that the app has no way to gain access to the user’s credentials. "

Answer (score 1):

@Jenny has the correct response.  However, for using MSAL against Azure AD, using an embedded webview prevents the prompt from displaying.

The key is this line...

```
.WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
```

Here is a more complete example when acquiring the token interactively.

```
        var authResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.B2CConstants.Scopes)
                                  .WithAccount(GetAccountByUsername(accounts, username))
                                  .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently added API for hide this dialog in Xamarin and Maui.

Option to hide prompt in iOS, when user attempts to login, iOS 13+ shows a prompt to the user. MSAL now provides an option to hide the prompt. To hide the prompt, create an instance of *SystemWebViewOptions* and set the *iOSHidePrivacyPrompt* to true.

Add the instance to PublicClientApplicationBuilder. That should hide the prompt.
e.g.

```
SystemWebViewOptions systemWebViewOptions = new SystemWebViewOptions()
{ 
    iOSHidePrivacyPrompt = true
};

var authResult = await pcaClient
    .AcquireTokenInteractive(configs.Scopes)
    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
    .WithParentActivityOrWindow(uiParent)
    .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
    .WithSystemWebViewOptions(systemWebViewOptions)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

If it works hit the upvote button